# eclipse org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles

Tags: ubuntu, java, eclipse

On ubuntu 18.04, eclipse fails after startup and also fail with its installer.

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2019-01-29 14:14:22.895
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4621)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4510)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4481)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:526)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.drawBackground(Control.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:6285)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5880)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.GTK._gtk_main_do_event(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.GTK.gtk_main_do_event(GTK.java:3969)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.eventProc(Display.java:1385)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS._g_main_context_iteration(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS.g_main_context_iteration(OS.java:1581)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:4470)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:822)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:798)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchPreferenceDialog.open(WorkbenchPreferenceDialog.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.OpenPreferencesAction.run(OpenPreferencesAction.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$4(ActionContributionItem.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:5663)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1386)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4931)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:4472)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1173)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1062)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:563)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1501)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1474)
```

Answer (score 1):

For me this fixed it:

```
export GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Although this may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain why and/or how it addresses the issue. Providing this additional context would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Thanks.

Comment: @fixer1234 you are right. But I really don't know how that fixes it. My understanding so far is that this environment variable makes eclipse use another Import "framework"? And it seems that whatever caused this is specific to an input thingy that is not the ibus thingy. Other than that this is a software bug in Eclipse.