# Debian 9: org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles immediately after opening Eclipse

Tags: debian, java, eclipse

I recently changed my laptop and installed Debian 9. On my new machine, I get the following error message almost immediately after opening the Eclipse installer:

> org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4725)  at
>   org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4614)  at
>   org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4585)  at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:532)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.drawBackground(Control.java:235)  at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:6800)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:6132)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.GTK._gtk_main_do_event(Native Method)    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.GTK.gtk_main_do_event(GTK.java:4166)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.eventProc(Display.java:1429)  at
>   org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS._g_main_context_iteration(Native
>   Method)   at
>   org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS.g_main_context_iteration(OS.java:1585)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:4661)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.AbstractSimpleDialog.show(AbstractSimpleDialog.java:155)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.InstallerApplication.run(InstallerApplication.java:250)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.InstallerApplication.start(InstallerApplication.java:408)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:660)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:597)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1468)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1441)

When I download Eclipse (2019-06) without the installer, I can open Eclipse succesfully, but after the first click (in the text editor or in the toolbar), I get

> Unhandled event loop exception No more handles

and then

> Internal Error An SWTError has occured. You are recommended to exit
>   the workbench. Subsequent errors may happen and may terminate the
>   workbench without warning. See the .log file for more details.
>
> Do you want to exit the workbench?

The logfile:

> !SESSION 2019-07-02 16:32:14.505
>   ----------------------------------------------- eclipse.buildId=4.12.0.I20190605-1800 java.version=1.8.0_212
>   java.vendor=Oracle Corporation BootLoader constants: OS=linux,
>   ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US Framework arguments:  -product
>   org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product Command-line arguments:  -os
>   linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product
>   org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
>
> This is a continuation of log file
>   /home/xxxxx/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.bak_0.log Created Time:
>   2019-07-02 16:32:42.144
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2019-07-02 16:32:42.144 !MESSAGE Error
>   occurred during status handling !STACK 0 org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No
>   more handles  at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4725)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4614)  at
>   org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4585)  at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:532)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.drawBackground(Control.java:235)  at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:6800)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:6132)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.GTK._gtk_main_do_event(Native Method)    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.GTK.gtk_main_do_event(GTK.java:4166)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.eventProc(Display.java:1429)  at
>   org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS._g_main_context_iteration(Native
>   Method)   at
>   org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS.g_main_context_iteration(OS.java:1585)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:4661)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.WorkbenchErrorHandler.showStatusAdapter(WorkbenchErrorHandler.java:84)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.WorkbenchErrorHandler.handle(WorkbenchErrorHandler.java:52)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.IDEWorkbenchErrorHandler.handle(IDEWorkbenchErrorHandler.java:105)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchErrorHandlerProxy.handle(WorkbenchErrorHandlerProxy.java:34)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java:214)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java:256)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java:266)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor.eventLoopException(WorkbenchAdvisor.java:325)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:65)
>     at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:827)    at
>   org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:799)     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.AboutDialog.lambda$0(AboutDialog.java:134)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:72)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.AboutDialog.buttonPressed(AboutDialog.java:130)
>     at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.lambda$0(Dialog.java:622)   at
>   org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener$1.widgetSelected(SelectionListener.java:84)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:252)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:5874)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1400)    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:5138)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:4663)
>     at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:823)    at
>   org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:799)     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.about.AboutHandler.execute(AboutHandler.java:31)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:283)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:95)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:320)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:254)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:173)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:156)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:498)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:488)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:213)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerService.executeCommand(LegacyHandlerService.java:392)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.runWithEvent(CommandAction.java:142)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:580)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$4(ActionContributionItem.java:412)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:5874)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1400)    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:5138)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:4663)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1173)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1062)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:635)   at
>   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:559)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:155)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:660)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:597)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1468)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1441)

I read everything I could find and tried the solutions as far as possible, but nothing worked for me so far. Especially, I tried the solutions from these threads:
[eclipse org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles](https://superuser.com/questions/1399663/eclipse-org-eclipse-swt-swterror-no-more-handles)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018553/swt-no-more-handles

I have no plugins installed, no hardware setup with several monitors and the error is not associated with any program I wrote myself (I could not even manage to open a file). I could not change the editor to window builder as proposed here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15594590/eclipse-bug-unhandled-event-loop-exception-no-more-handles ) because Eclipse crashes too fast.

Any help will be greatly apreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem at home
.
I was able to solve it by doing in the terminal as root:

`im-config`

I confirmed by yes the two following screens.

I selected cjkv among the different choices.
[selection screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NLVn.png)

I confirmed by OK

I restarted my PC and the problem has been solved.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! After several days of work, your proposed steps solved the problem immediately!!!